Galilean transformation vs boost matrices
I'm confused about the difference between a Galilean transformation and boost with reference to their matrices. I was given four statements (listed below) but I'm not sure what I should be looking for to determine their validity. Apologies if this has been answered before I could only see boost vs translation but wasn't sure if this was the same.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
v & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
-v & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$  is a Galilean transformation

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
v & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
2v & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$  is a Galilean transformation

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
v & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
v & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-v & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$  is a Galilean boost

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2v & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
v & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2v & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$  is a Galilean transformation but not a Galilean boost



Do you understand how to write the linear transformations between $t,x,y,z$ and $t’,x’,y’,z’$ that these matrices represent?

@Ghoster I think so, you just multiply by [t, x, y, z] transpose. I know from the solution I was given that the issue is with the first matrix so I'm assuming it is something to do with x' = vt + x + z but I dont really know how to interpret this or why it is an issue
